# What would be the output for this state table?

Tags: boolean-algebra, finite-state-machine, boolean

I am having doubts on how to do the karnaugh map for the output of this state table:

[image]

Since the output has 2 variables how can I make a karnaugh map with the output result?

For example for the state Q1 ( Q1,Q2) I would do:

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am specifically asking: Since the output has 2 variables how can I make a karnaugh map with the output result?